# spring configuration with system property

Tags: spring, properties

I have a question. Currently i start jboss with -P property that links to file with properties.
In this property file i have property - mongo.server.list=127.0.0.1. In Spring configuration i try to set this property as value of constructor of bean. But spring treat ${mongo.server.list} as value itself.

Here is the code

```
<bean id="systemPropertyConfigurer"
   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
</bean>

<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <value>${mongo.server.list}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your property file as a JVM property and read it in spring mvc configuration file as:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///${-P}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the property as a JVM arg as -Dmongo.server.list=....

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to start your server using `-Dmongo.server.list=127.0.0.1` ? (i.e. using `-D` instead of `-P`, and no space between `-D` and the property name)